# How to load in customized qgis model and run it with python script?

Tags: python, qgis

I have a customized qgis model (.model3 file) saved on my computer, with the path: "path/to/myModel.model3", and I am building a qgis plugin. I would like to somehow load or import this model file inside qgis plugin and run it and obtain the result with python code (probably processing module). How to achieve this?

What I have tried:
I ran the model with the traditional gui approach and checked the processing history and obtained the processing.run("model:myModel", {xxxxxx}) code. But running this requires me to click the "Add model to toolbox" button to load the model from file in the first place. Otherwise, python will complain "Algorithm model:myModel not found". Is there a scripting way to load model in?

I know that maybe loading the model manually before running the plugin will work, as it tells Qgis the presence of this customized model, but how to automate this loading part as well with script?

I also know that I can export the model as python script and replicate the processing steps within in the plugin, so that I do not need to load it. But this is bad, in that if the model is updated, I have to export and replicate again.

Basically, I want to achieve below in the plugin:

```
model_path = 'path/to/myModel.model3'
// load in model to Qgis somehow
processing.run("model:myModel", {xxxxxx})
```

thanks.